# Find all the shell used among all the duplicate users in etc/passwd file

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, shell

I have tried to find the duplicate username in /etc/passwd file in the following way:

```
#!/bin/bash

# passwd file are look like below
# username : password : user ID : group ID : user ID info : home directory : command shell

cut -d: -f1 passwd | sort | uniq -d|
while IFS=: read -r user_name;
do
    echo "$user_name"
done
```

Then I tried to find the list of the unique shell used among all these duplicate users. But don't know how to do that.

Is there any way to display the unique shell used by all these duplicate users?

My etc/passwd file is given below:

```
imshakil:x:1000:1000:Mobarak Hosen Shakil,,,:/home/imshakil:/bin/bash
nm-openvpn:x:122:129:NetworkManager OpenVPN,,,:/var/lib/openvpn/chroot:/usr/sbin/nologin
lightdm:x:123:131:Light Display Manager:/var/lib/lightdm:/bin/false
hadoop:x:1001:1001:Bigger Hadoop,,,:/home/hadoop:/bin/bash
sshd:x:124:65534::/run/sshd:/usr/sbin/nologin
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
daemon:x:1:1:daemon:/usr/sbin:/usr/sbin/nologin
bin:x:2:2:bin:/bin:/usr/sbin/nologin
sys:x:3:3:sys:/dev:/usr/sbin/nologin
sync:x:4:65534:sync:/bin:/bin/sync
games:x:5:60:games:/usr/games:/usr/sbin/nologin
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
daemon:x:1:1:daemon:/usr/sbin:/usr/sbin/nologin
bin:x:2:2:bin:/bin:/usr/sbin/nologin
sys:x:3:3:sys:/dev:/usr/sbin/nologin
sync:x:4:65534:sync:/bin:/bin/sync
gdm:x:121:127:Gnome Display Manager:/var/lib/gdm3:/bin/false
imshakil:x:1000:1000:Mobarak Hosen Shakil,,,:/home/imshakil:/bin/bash
nm-openvpn:x:122:129:NetworkManager OpenVPN,,,:/var/lib/openvpn/chroot:/usr/sbin/nologin
lightdm:x:123:131:Light Display Manager:/var/lib/lightdm:/bin/false
hadoop:x:1001:1001:Bigger Hadoop,,,:/home/hadoop:/bin/bash
sshd:x:124:65534::/run/sshd:/usr/sbin/nologin
```

I need to get output like below:
duplicate users:

```
bin
daemon
hadoop
imshakil
lightdm
nm-openvpn
root
sshd
sync
sys
```

and list of shell used by them:

```
/bin/bash
/bin/false
/bin/sync
/usr/sbin/nologin
```

(updated)

Comment: The term "duplicate" is being used confusingly here. In what way are these users "duplicates"?

Comment: Your while-read loop is pointless: it simply reads and writes what is coming down a pipe anyway. But changing -f1 to -f7 would do the job.

Comment: I didn't believe you could cram a duplicate user into /etc/passwd, but nm-openvpm seems to have done it. I wonder if that user has two different passwords?

Comment: Actually I have edited the /etc/passwd file to make some duplicate username.

Comment: I have updated my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do

```bsh
sort /etc/passwd | uniq -c | grep -vE '^ +1 ' | cut -d: -f 7 | sort -u
```

or all in awk

```bsh
awk -F: '++count[$1] == 2 {shell[$NF]} END {for (s in shell) print s}' /etc/passwd
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `>=`, to allow for duplicates that differ in their shell fields?

Comment: I suppose. The requirements are unclear

Comment: Thanks @glennjackman It works as expected.

Comment: I have modified as below:
awk -F: '++count[$1] >= 2 {shell[$NF]} END {for (s in shell) print s}' passed

Comment: The difference being (a) my version takes the shell from the _2nd_ occurrence of the duplicated name, vs (b) yours takes the shell from the _last_ occurrence.

Answer (score 0):

The following command will **only** compare the username, ignore any differences in other fields (e.g. uid, gid, homedir, shell) and pick up **all** shells used by duplicate usernames.

```bsh
grep -f <(cut -d: -f1 /etc/passwd | sort | uniq -d | sed -e "s/^/^/") /etc/passwd | cut -d: -f7 | sort -u
```